# gfortran: all terminall output goes to fort.6 instead of terminal

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have a program which contains some output to terminal like this:

```
write(*,*) 'Progress...'
```

When I run it from command line or by double click (I use windows) all terminal output goes to fort.6 file.
Is there any method to output it to the window?

A short program was tested:

```
program testoutput
write(*,*) 'test1'
write(*,*) 'test2'
write(*,*) 'test3'
write(*,*) 'test4'
write(*,*) 'test5'
write(*,*) 'test6'
write(*,*) 'test7'
write(*,*) 'test8'
write(*,*) 'test9'
write(*,*) 'test10'
end program
```

And it works fine - I see output in terminal.
But another program does not work the same way. I do not use unit 6 for output.
Also I guess it is impossible to show it here since it is really big.

Comment: It seems you have misunderstood the point of a minimal, complete and verifiable example (mcve) https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Your example code **must** display the desired behavior. How can we help you otherwise?

Answer (score 2):

One way to reproduce what you're seeing is

```
program fort6
  implicit none
  close(6)
  write(*,*) 'Progress...'
end program fort6
```

So how to avoid this kind of problem? I good rule of thumb is to ALWAYS use unit numbers larger than 10. Or even better if you don't need to retain compatibility with old compilers, open files with the `NEWUNIT=` specifier instead of manually assigning a unit number.

Comment: I do not use unit=6. I just write some information to terminal using $write(*,*). After executing this program all information is outputted to fort.6 file, terminal is empty. I have tried to close unit 6 jsut in case. But it did not help.

Comment: @KonstantinEbauer: Well, then I'll just repeat my request for a MCVE.

Comment: I have tried a test program and it works (added it to the question). But another program works wrong. I have checked all libraries and exclude wirte(6,*) output. it still creates fort.6 with all the output which I expect to see in terminal/in window

Comment: @KonstantinEbauer: Try checking all your close statements. write(6,*) is equivalent to write(*,*) on gfortran, what you need to figure out is why the stdout unit is closed.

Comment: Found it! Only once unit=6 is used by a subroutine. Replaced it with another unit number and everything is working now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you write to a unit that hasn't been explicitly associated with anything, for example:

```
program test
    implicit none
    write (27, *) "Hello"
end program test
```

it will create a file called `fort.27` and write to it.

For many (but not all) compilers, unit 6 is the standard output.

For those compilers, **and only those**, the statements `write(*, *)` and `write(6, *)` would be identical. Consequently, on those compilers, closing unit 6 would cause further output of the form `write(*, *)` to be send to a file called `fort.6`.

I see from your comment to another answer that you have found a subroutine that does something along these lines. But I wanted to write this as an answer all the same.